# how to create query to list categories in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

i got this in my view.py and want to list all categories

```
def home(request):

    category = Category.objects.all()

    context = {

        'category': category,
    }

    return render(request, 'courses/index.html', context)
```

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)


class Course(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

but im getting this output from print :

```
<QuerySet [<Category: Courses>, <Category: Computers>]>
```

can someone help me with this

Comment: This is how it supposed to be in Django. You may need to iterate over it (in template, most cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `category` is *not* a single category. But a collection of categories, you need to *iterate* over it, like:

```
def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/index.html', context)
```

In the template you iterate and can render this with:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**: you can annotate your queryset with the number of *related* `Course` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.annotate(
        num_courses=Count('course')
    )
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/index.html', context)
```

Then you can render this with:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category }}: {{ category.num_courses }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank You , thats is what i was looking for

Comment: i have one more question , i have listed the categories now , but how can i get count for products in each category to show alongside the category ?

Comment: @mar: is `Course` the "product"?

Comment: @mar: see an edit for the number of related `Course`s. You can update it accordingly for another related model.

Comment: @mar: then see the EDIT part of the answer.